# sort excel columns using pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I want to sort the excel file  worksheet called "LTE_PrbUtil" and it has a column called "CELL" which is string descending. 
When I run the program and find some error:

```
  File "C:\Users\p4532\Desktop\QGIS_project\highloading.py", line 18, in <module> df = df.sort(columns="CELL")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 3081, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'sort'`
```

Here is my code:

```
import shutil
import pandas as pd
import xlrd
xl=pd.ExcelFile("C:\Users\p4532\Desktop\QGIS_project\HighUtilCells_new.xlsx")                                                                           
df = xl.parse("LTE_PrbUtil")
df = df.sort(columns="CELL")
```

It seems the dataframe cannot recognize `sort`.
Can anyone help?

Comment: `sort` is deprecated.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html#pandas-dataframe-sort-values):

```
df = df.sort_values('CELL')
```